# I dont get anything after firing DPUMP - IMPDP command

Tags: oracle, .profile, impdp

```
ORACLE_HOME="/oravl01/oracle/11.2.0.4"

impdp /oravl01/oracle/11.2.0.4/bin/impdp AST3APPO/astdb90@CNVABP90 DIRECTORY=DPUMP DUMPFILE=expdp_CUSTOMER_DOX_%u.dmp LOGFILE=CUSTOMER.log JOB_NAME=CUSTOMER_IM TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND REMAP_TABLE=CUSTOMER_DOX:CUSTOMER REMAP_SCHEMA=MIGUSER:AST3APPO REMAP_TABLESPACE=migration:migration CONTENT=DATA_ONLY PARALLEL=8
```

Nothing appears on the screen after that .

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Is there any way that I can see the output of impdp apart from the terminal? MIGUSER is my source username where customer_dox resides and dump file is created, I could see that. I need to import it to AST3APPO schema

Comment: Issue was with the oracle_home not set in .profile file, added the same and now which sqlplus and which impdp both show the correct oracle version i.e, 11 g

Comment: Now the issue I'm facing is with the invalid username/pwd, Though I'm able to login through the same user creds using sqlplus but when providing the same along with the impdp command, I get invalid username. can anyone please tell me why?

Comment: Import: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Jun 5 14:23:30 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
UDI-00002: invalid username or password

Comment: I guess you are working as system user for datapump right ? and please can you mention what is the commad you are using for the datapump ?

Comment: Why do you have both the plain `impdp` and the full path to that shown? Are you really providing both? If so it may just be trying to interpret the full-path version *as* the username? Use one or the other not both.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0):

You've figured the initial problem, which was that ORACLE_HOME either wasn't set or wasn't exported in your environment, and your PATH didn't include $ORACLE_HOME/bin. Setting those up in your .profile has fixed that.

You've shown the command you're running as:

```
impdp /oravl01/oracle/11.2.0.4/bin/impdp AST3APPO/astdb90@CNVABP90 ...
```

That looks like you've tried a few things before fixing the PATH issue. You've ended up with two references to the binary. The first plain `impdp` is now being recognised from your PATH, but you also have the full path to the binary as the first argument, and [the first argument is interpreted as the username/password](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL958). So you need to remove that:

```
impdp AST3APPO/astdb90@CNVABP90 ...
```

Or with the full path, which isn't necessary now:

```
/oravl01/oracle/11.2.0.4/bin/impdp AST3APPO/astdb90@CNVABP90 ...
```

But not both.

Comment: Thanks Alex --minor issue but big impact. removed impdp , was kind of typo in the code.. running successfully now